# Write a Lex rule to detect the quote symbol

Tags: c, lex

I want to ask you how to write a Lex code to detect quote symbols ( " ) This is my Lex code:

```
%e  1019
%p  2807
%n  371
%k  284
%a  1213
%o  1117

Q   \"         /* Definition of Quote*/
O   [0-7]
D   [0-9]
NZ  [1-9]
L   [a-zA-Z_]
A   [a-zA-Z_0-9]
H   [a-fA-F0-9]
HP  (0[xX])
E   ([Ee][+-]?{D}+)
P   ([Pp][+-]?{D}+)
FS  (f|F|l|L)
IS  (((u|U)(l|L|ll|LL)?)|((l|L|ll|LL)(u|U)?))
CP  (u|U|L)
SP  (u8|u|U|L)
ES  (\\(['"\?\\abfnrtv]|[0-7]{1,3}|x[a-fA-F0-9]+))
WS  [ \t\v\n\f]

%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"

    extern void yyerror(const char *);  

    extern int sym_type(const char *);  

    #define sym_type(identifier) IDENTIFIER 

    static void comment(void);
    static int check_type(void);
%}

%%
Q                       {yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '"';} /*Rule to detect quotes*/
"/*"                                    { comment(); }
"//".*                                    { }

"include"               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(INCLUDE); } /*Line 44*/
"void"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(VOID); }
"int"                   { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(INT); } 
"long"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(LONG); }
"char"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(CHAR); }
"short"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(SHORT); }
"signed"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(SIGNED); }
"double"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(DOUBLE); }
"unsigned"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(UNSIGNED); }
"float"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(FLOAT); }


"auto"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(AUTO); } 
"extern"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(EXTERN); }
"register"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(REGISTER); }
"static"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(STATIC); }


"const"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(CONST); } 
"restrict"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(RESTRICT); }
"volatile"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(VOLATILE); }
"_Atomic"               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ATOMIC; }


"break"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(BREAK); }
"case"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(CASE); }

"continue"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(CONTINUE); }
"default"               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(DEFAULT); }
"do"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(DO); }
"else"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(ELSE); }
"enum"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(ENUM); }

"for"                   { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(FOR); }
"goto"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(GOTO); }
"if"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(IF); }
"inline"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(INLINE); }


"return"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(RETURN); }
"sizeof"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(SIZEOF); }

"struct"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(STRUCT); }
"switch"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(SWITCH); }
"typedef"               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(TYPEDEF); }
"union"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(UNION); }



"while"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(WHILE); }
"_Alignas"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ALIGNAS; }
"_Alignof"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ALIGNOF; }

"_Bool"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return BOOL; }
"_Complex"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return COMPLEX; }
"_Generic"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return GENERIC; }
"_Imaginary"            { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return IMAGINARY; }
"_Noreturn"             { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return NORETURN; }
"_Static_assert"        { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return STATIC_ASSERT; }
"_Thread_local"         { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return THREAD_LOCAL; }
"__func__"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return FUNC_NAME; }


{L}{A}*                 {  return check_type(); } /*Line 107*/

{HP}{H}+{IS}?               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return I_CONSTANT; }
{NZ}{D}*{IS}?               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return I_CONSTANT; }
"0"{O}*{IS}?                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return I_CONSTANT; }
{CP}?"'"([^'\\\n]|{ES})+"'"     { return I_CONSTANT; } /**/

{D}+{E}{FS}?                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return F_CONSTANT; }
{D}*"."{D}+{E}?{FS}?        { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return F_CONSTANT; }
{D}+"."{E}?{FS}?            { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return F_CONSTANT; }
{HP}{H}+{P}{FS}?            { yylval.a=strdup(yytext);return F_CONSTANT; }
{HP}{H}*"."{H}+{P}{FS}?     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return F_CONSTANT; }
{HP}{H}+"."{P}{FS}?         { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return F_CONSTANT; }

({SP}?\"([^"\\\n]|{ES})*\"{WS}*)+   { return STRING_LITERAL; }


"..."                   { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ELLIPSIS; }
">>="                   { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return RIGHT_ASSIGN; }
"<<="                   { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return LEFT_ASSIGN; }
"+="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ADD_ASSIGN; }
"-="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return SUB_ASSIGN; }
"*="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return MUL_ASSIGN; }
"/="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return DIV_ASSIGN; }
"%="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return MOD_ASSIGN; }
"&="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return AND_ASSIGN; }
"^="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return XOR_ASSIGN; }
"|="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return OR_ASSIGN; }
">>"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return RIGHT_OP; }
"<<"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return LEFT_OP; }
"++"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return INC_OP; }
"--"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return DEC_OP; }
"->"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return PTR_OP; }
"&&"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return AND_OP; }
"||"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return OR_OP; }
"<="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return LE_OP; }
">="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return GE_OP; }
"=="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return EQ_OP; }
"!="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return NE_OP; }
";"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ';'; }
("{"|"<%")              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '{'; }
("}"|"%>")              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '}'; }
","                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ','; }
":"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ':'; }
"="                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '='; }
"("                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '('; }
")"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ')'; }
("["|"<:")              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '['; }
("]"|":>")              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ']'; }
"."                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '.'; } /*Line 156*/
"&"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '&'; }
"!"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '!'; }
"~"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '~'; }
"-"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '-'; }
"+"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '+'; }
"*"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '*'; }
"/"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '/'; }
"%"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '%'; }
"<"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '<'; }
">"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '>'; }
"^"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '^'; }
"|"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '|'; }
"?"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '?'; }
"#"                     {yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '#'; }   /*Line 170*/




{WS}+                   { /* whitespace separates tokens */ }
.                   { /* discard bad characters */ }  /*Line 176*/

%%

int yywrap(void)        /* called at end of input */
{
    return 1;           /* terminate now */
}

static void comment(void)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = input()) != 0)
    if (c == '*')
    {
        printf("1: %d\n",c);
        while ((c = input()) == '*')
        ;
        printf("2: %d\n",c);
        if (c == '/')
        return;
        if (c == 0)
        printf("3: %d\n",c);
        break;
    }
    yyerror("unterminated comment");
}

static int check_type(void)
{
    switch (sym_type(yytext))
    {
        case TYPEDEF_NAME:                /* previously defined */
            {
            return TYPEDEF_NAME;
            }
        case ENUMERATION_CONSTANT:        /* previously defined */
        return ENUMERATION_CONSTANT;
        default:                          /* includes undefined */ /*This is when do normal declaration such as int a=3; in this case it return a*/
            {
            yylval.a=strdup(yytext);
            return IDENTIFIER;
            }
    }
}
```

And this is some relevant part of the Yacc code:

```
include
: '#' INCLUDE '<' IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER '>' {printf("The first rule\n");}
| '#' INCLUDE '"' IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER '"' {printf("The second rule\n");}
;
```

The problem (I think) is on definition part: `Q \"` When I compiled Lex and ran along with Yacc code. Assume I input a sentence: `#include"header.h"` The output is:

```
--accepting rule at line 170 ("#")
--accepting rule at line 44 ("include")
--accepting rule at line 176 ("?")
--accepting rule at line 176 ("?")
--accepting rule at line 176 ("?")
--accepting rule at line 107 ("header")
```

**Note that I wrote a number of line, on the Lex code, corresponding to the error above.**

As you can see the *# include* are tokenized without any problems but *header . h* aren't okay, it ended up as `?`. Especially, The comma . should be match in rule "." in line 156 but it ended up as rule 176. Also *header* and *h* should be matched in rule {L}{A}* of Line 107. What should I do to fix this problem?

And additional question: when I put `Q  {yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '"';}` after line 170, I got error said `warning, rule cannot be matched` I want to ask why it became like that?

> ### EDIT

**I tried to use {Q}, also rearranged the rules, that is, to put the rules with keyword (such as "include","void","if") in the first priority. But it didn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this?**

Comment: Surely you can make a *minimal*, complete, and verifiable example out of that.

Comment: But do note that you appear to have written a rule for `Q` where you meant to write one for `{Q}`.

Comment: I think @JohnBollinger has it cased. Although, as I'm sure I've mentioned before, using `\"` *directly* in the pattern (as you do in the pattern for string literals) is more readable and less error-prone than over-reliance on pattern macros. Anyway, I'd expect `"header.h"` to match the string literal rule, regardless of Qs. The fact that it din't combined with the fact that apparently three bad tokens were produced for what appears to be a single quote character makes me wonder if the input wasn't actually a typographic quote.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Does it has a thing to do with the rule priority or something?

Comment: @Hajime I came to the same conclusion like [rici](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) and will elaborate it a little bit: Even if you use `{Q}` or `\"` or `"\""` it will not match the `"` in `#include "header.h"` because **this** rule `({SP}?\"([^"\\\n]|{ES})*\"{WS}*)+   { return STRING_LITERAL; }` will match `"header.h"`. According to the lex/flex manual: 1. The rule is applied which matches the most characters. 2. If two (or more) rules match with equal length then the first (e.g. the upper most in source code) is chosen.